# How do I interface with extern variables from Cheerp/js?

Tags: javascript, c++, llvm, screeps, cheerp

[Cheerp](https://github.com/leaningtech/cheerp-meta) is a C++ to js/wasm transpiler. [Screeps](https://screeps.com/) is a programming videogame.

How do I read in the [`Game.time`](https://docs.screeps.com/api/#Game.time) variable from my transpiled C++ code? (in screeps)

---

```
#include <cheerp/client.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace client {
    class Game : public Object {
    public:
        static volatile double time;
    };  

    extern volatile Game &Game;
}

void webMain() {
    cout << __TIME__ << ": The current time is: " << client::Game.time << endl;
}
```

I have tried any number of variations on:

- `extern`, `volatile` and `static`
- references and pointers
- both `client` and `cheerp` namespaces
- Inheriting from `Node`/`Object`
- `int32_t` vs `double` vs `float` as a type

I seem to get either:

- `NaN`
- `0`
- `1`
- fatal type handling errors in the compiled code

How do I correctly interface with Javascript Objects and variables from within my C++ code? The cheerp documentation is VERY sparse to say the least...

---

Note: cheerp is never actually generating the proper Javascript. There's always some inconsistency as to how the `Game` object is handled and in a lot of scenarios it's incorrectly trying to index `Game.d` as an array instead of `Game.time`.

Comment: This question MAY be identical to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56853261/how-to-preserve-variable-name-in-cheerp-a-c-to-javascript-transpiler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes declared in the `client` namespace should have no member fields.

To access external JS objects properties you need to add methods starting with `get_` and `set_`, to respectively read and write to the property:

```
#include <cheerp/client.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace client {
    class Game : public Object {
    public:
        double get_time();
    };  

    extern Game &Game;
}

void webMain() {
    cout << __TIME__ << ": The current time is: " << client::Game.get_time() << endl;
}
```

Also, you don't need to use volatile here.

Comment: But what about arrays or complex types? How does that work?

Comment: you can use pointers to basic types for arrays, and pointers to other client objects for nested objects:
https://pastebin.com/DqTT8LN0